# How useful would mass EM communication be in Space?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Considering a Science Fiction question, it occured to me that in "populated" space, with no atmosphere, you might expect to find more EM interference than on Earth.

Basically, if you are outside of an atmosphere, are there issues with using radio as a mass communication method, based on the difficulties with spectrum management when the atmosphere isn't degrading signals?

And would there actually be more interference from the radio emissions of celestial bodies once you leave Earth's atmosphere?

Comment: Note than its *impossible* to comunicate via sound in vacuum.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Obviously, but the idea was that if you couldn't practically use EM out of atmosphere, then you might as well use sound within the atmosphere. Spurious, but it's out of scope for the question I'm asking here.

Comment: The robots in movies are communicating with sound because it serves the plot. After all... would you want to watch a movie where the human protagonist is screaming at his robots all the time "What did you say to him just now! I demand that you tell me what you said to that other robot over Wifi or I swear I will take your transponder out!". In real life, of course, we are communicating with electromagnetic waves over distances of 10 billion kilometers just fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on movies.SE.

Comment: @curiousone I've edited the question to focus more on the scientific question I want answered and removed the cross-link.

Comment: Your premise is still wrong. Electromagnetic communication works in space just fine. NASA has plenty of pretty pictures for you that were transmitted from the entire solar system by means of electromagnetic waves. The atmosphere is not degrading electromagnetic signals below approx. 60GHz, which is a band that has been suggested for cellular data networks for quite a while, but neither the technology nor the demand are there, so far.

Comment: @CuriousOne I understand that, I guess my question is how do these signals avoid trampling on each other and getting distorted by radiation from natural sources?

Comment: The signals don't avoid that, the protocols and spectral assignments by the national and international regulators do. Each transponder is being assigned a max. transmission level, a spectral mask and a few other properties that guarantee that it leaves enough useful bandwidth and signal to noise ratio for other transponders within a defined (and technology dependent) spatial volume. Other than that the extreme linearity of spacetime for em waves guarantees that the signals don't mix out of band. That's also the reason why we won't be running out of useful bandwidth any time soon.

Comment: @CuriousOne See, this is really interesting, I guess I'm misunderstanding how that spatial volume is controlled (which is why I asked the question). Also, I'm not sure I understand the phrase "extreme linearity of spacetime". I'd love to continue this, but chat would be the place to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34142/discussion-between-curiousone-and-deworde).